# How to focus an invisible input text box in Javascript? Should I use what style?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to focus an invisible input text box but it seems that the "display: none" is not working.

Should I use:

```
width: 0; height: 0;
```

or

```
visibility: hidden;
```

or

```
opacity: 0;
```

or any other else?

Is it possible to focus a invisible input text?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question. This is what am trying to explain.

I have a textbox within a div that is hidden  ( `style="display:none"`) when the page is loaded, and on based on the checkbox (next to it) select, this input will be visible to user.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#chkBox').click(function(){
            if($('#chkBox').prop('checked')){
                $('#div_input_value').css({'display':'block'});
            }else{
                $('#div_input_value').css({'display':'none'});
            }
        })});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#chkBox').click(function(){
            if($('#chkBox').prop('checked')){
                $('#div_input_value').show();
            }else{
                $('#div_input_value').hide();
            }
        })});
```

This uses jQuery and the .show() method to make the element visible, and is the counter to .hide(); in JavaScript.  This should work.